# How to ensure Python3 infers numbers as a string instead of an integer?

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2

I have a line of code here:

```
query = """SELECT v.retailiqpo_ordernumber 
    FROM public.vmi_purchase_orders v
    WHERE v.vendor_account = {}""".format(str(primary_account_number))
```

I tried to load in the string value of the number, but psycopg2 still throws this error.

```
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: operator does not exist: character varying = integer
```

What options do I have to ensure Psycopg2 sees this as a string? Or should I just change the overall structure of the database to just  integers?

Comment: @Andomar if you omit positional numbers inside `{}` in strings, they are taken in order given inside format

Comment: @PatrickArtner: Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>Use</strike>

```
query = """
SELECT v.retailiqpo_ordernumber 
FROM public.vmi_purchase_orders v 
WHERE v.vendor_account = '{}'
""".format(primary_account_number)
```

That way the number inside your query is passed as a string - if your `c.vendor_account` *is* of a stringtype (varchar i.e.). The important part are the `'` before/after `{}` so the query string sees it as string.

---

As Jon Clements pointed out, it is better to let the api handle the conversion:

```
query = """
SELECT v.retailiqpo_ordernumber 
FROM public.vmi_purchase_orders v 
WHERE v.vendor_account = %s
"""

cursor.execute(query, (str(primary_account_number),)
```

Doku: [Psycopg - Passing parameters to sql queries](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries)

Comment: Always better to let the library sort these things out - make the query: `where v.vendor_account = %s` and then explicitly make the `cursor.execute(query, (str(primary_account_number),)` call... That way you're not dealing with string formatting, and the underlying db api library will correctly escape whatever it needs to, to make it work correctly.

Answer (score 2):

It's (almost) always better to let psycopg2 interpolate query parameters for you. (http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#the-problem-with-the-query-parameters)

```
query = """SELECT v.retailiqpo_ordernumber 
    FROM public.vmi_purchase_orders v
    WHERE v.vendor_account = %s"""

cur.execute(query, (str(primary_account_number),))
```

This way psycopg2 will deal with the proper type formatting based on the type of the python value passed.